# IF formula in excel 2019

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

The below formula works properly but for the empty cells, it returns #value!

```
=IF(S4=0," ",IF(E4-S4>=3,"improved",IF(E4-S4<=4,"Not Improved")))
```

I want the S4 and E4 = 0 the result comes empty means it comes blank, don't show me #VALUE! . thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try formula auditing, more exactly "Evaluate Formula"? This gives you the possibility to see when exactly your problem appears.

Answer (score 0):

So use iferror():

Wrap your existing formula like so:

```
=iferror(IF(S4=0," ",IF(E4-S4>=3,"improved",IF(E4-S4<=4,"Not Improved")))),”Check error”)
```

Replace check error with what you want : a warning, a number etc

Note your first logical test is looking for a space “ “, if you want blank use “”

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error with `IFERROR` the other answer suggests.

An alternative would be to prevent the error in the first place.
It is occurring because you are treating the blanks as 0 when they are not.

You can explicitly state this in a number of ways, but one of the simplest is to wrap `E4` & `S4` in a `SUM` function:

```
=IF(SUM(S4)=0, " ", IF(SUM(E4)-SUM(S4)>=3, "improved", IF(SUM(E4)-SUM(S4)<=4, "Not Improved")))
```